# How to use a war for Rest API in wildfly

Tags: gradle, wildfly-10, teiid

I have a war file consisting of my spring programs. I want to use it in wildfly 10. Deployed it in server successfully.
What are the next steps to be followed to use the war file.
I am using 
 Wildfly 10
 Jboss AS 7.1.1
 JBDS 11

Comment: I believe if you copy the `.war` file in the `deployments` folder of the server, it will be deployed and you should be able to access the pages using the URL.